# How do I capitalize the first letter of a list item (ignoring the bullet)?

Tags: key-bindings

I have a list:

```
- item one
- item two
- item three
and this as well.
```

and I want to capitalize the first word in a line.

However the two bindings that I know to go to the first character of a line '0' and '_' go to the dash (-) not the i in item.

Is there a way to create leader key shortcut that will automatically capitalize the first letter of a sentence or list (needs to ignore the leading "-")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the following should work for you

```vim
:nnoremap <leader>c <Cmd>s/\a/\u&/<CR>
:vnoremap <leader>c <Cmd>'<,'>s/\a/\u&<CR>
```

The first command will map `<leader>c` (for **c**apitalize, but pick any letter) to the following `:substitute` command. The pattern matches the first alphabetic character `\a` (see `:help /\a`). It will be replaced by an uppercase version of the match `\u&` (see `:help s/\u` and `:help s/\&`). Thus, lowercase letters will be replaced with their capitalized version and uppercase letters with themselves.

The second command is the first one's companion for visual and select modes. With it, you can select several lines and change them all at once.

Comment: thank you! I'm not used to  Vim's special regex commands so this is helpful

Comment: @alejandro_hagan you're welcome. If you want to familiarize yourself with Vim's regexp dialect, you might find `:help pattern` useful as well :-)